# Angular Tables mat-table and cdk-table

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk, mat-table

What is the difference in angular's mat-table and cdk-table and in mat-table can we render rows of table after it has been created once.

Answer (score 3):

As you can read from `Angular Material`'s doc, `mat-table` 'extends' the `CDKTable`.
They has the same API, but with `mat-table` you have the standard of [Material Design](https://material.io/design/)

Comment: how can we add a row dynamically on a button click event in material table, is it will be same in both or different?

Comment: You should just update the Table's `dataSource` just with a `push`.

Answer (score 1):

From the Angular Material documentation.

> The mat-table provides a Material Design styled data-table that can be
>   used to display rows of data.
>
> This table builds on the foundation of the CDK data-table and uses a
>   similar interface for its data input and template, except that its
>   element and attribute selectors will be prefixed with mat- instead of
>   cdk-.

https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview